# Why is the named IIFE logged instead of the variable with the same name?

Tags: javascript, iife

I saw the code below that someone posted. I’m confused about what it logs. It logs the *function* `a`, not `200`. Why?

```js
var a = 1;
(function a() {
  a = 200;
  console.log(a)
})()
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering what is IIFE? then its Immediately Invoked Function Expression or Self-Executing Anonymous Function

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because the function being immediately invoked is *named*, and that name cannot be reassigned to refer to something else *directly* inside the IIFE.

Any named function expressions will exhibit this behavior as well. A function expression whose function is named `a` will mean that `a` directly inside the function will always refer to the function itself, even if you try to reassign it.

You can make the error explicit if you use strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
var a = 1;
(function a() {
  a = 200;
  console.log(a)
})()
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Having a named function expression is a bit like having

```
(function a() {
  const a = <this function>;
  // ...
})()
```

except trying to reassign it will only throw in strict mode.

Specifically, I believe the ECMAScript 5 specification for this behavior is in [SetMutableBinding](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1.1.3):

> 3. If the binding for N in envRec is a mutable binding, change its bound value to V.
> 4. Else this must be an attempt to change the value of an immutable binding so if S (strict mode being used) if true throw a TypeError exception.

But directly inside a function, the function name binding is not mutable - see [Function Definition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13):

> The production
>
> `FunctionExpression : function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }`
>
> is evaluated as follows:
>
> Call the **CreateImmutableBinding** concrete method of envRec, passing the String value of `Identifier` as the argument.

Comment: Could you point to some specs about this behavior. For one, I suspect it doesn't need to be "Immediately Invoked", `setTimeout((function a() { a = 200; console.log(a) }), 1000)` would act the same.

Comment: Got it, [it's here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#_ref_13324) and as suspected, it applies to all named *FunctionExpressions*, not only *ImmediatelyInvoked* ones (which I don't think are a thing in the language, just a usage)