# Why can't the name of a function expression be reassigned?

Tags: javascript, function

Why will the following snippet throw an error?

```js
"use strict";
(function a() {
  console.log(typeof a); // function
  console.log(a = 0); // error
})();
```

Why doesn't this snippet throw an error?

```js
"use strict";
(function() {
  function a() {
    console.log(a = 0); // 0
  }
  return a;
})()();
```

Why does immediately returning the function throw an error?

```js
"use strict";
(function() {
  return function a() {
    console.log(a = 0); // error
  };
})()();
```

Are function expressions the only case where this happens? Why can't they be reassigned?

Comment: In the first example `a` is the name of the function but it's not an actual binding in the environment. Same as if you did `foo = function bar() {}` - you cannot call `bar()` as that identifier doesn't exist.

Comment: @VLAZ But you *can* call `a()` inside `a` in that first example…

Comment: @deceze ah, true. I somehow completely misread the first example as trying to reassign `a` outside of it...

Comment: Quick stab as for why the second example doesn't throw an error: because it's a function declaration instead of a function expression. Named function expressions have weird and special rules about their name being used inside of them. Function declarations are just variables in their scope.

Comment: Yes, it’s a named function expression thing. And `class` thing from inside the class, now (`class X { constructor() { X = 0; } } new X(); /* fails */ X = 0; /* sets */`). Why? Because the spec says so.

Comment: @deceze I was just using the second example to show that the name of the function  can be reassinged under normal circumstances.

Comment: For the 3rd point, it's not returning the function that makes it throw the error, but the call to the returned function, which falls back to your first point.

Comment: Sooo, does this answer the question?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882321/476

Comment: @deceze My question originated from that. Posed the samed question as a comment. Didn't get a response so I deleted the comment and posted this question. Hadn't seen the edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's how named FunctionExpressions behave, which is different than how *FunctionDeclarations* do

The rules to [create a named *FunctionExpression* are](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#_ref_13324):

> FunctionExpression:functionBindingIdentifier(FormalParameters){FunctionBody}
>
> 1. Let scope be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. Let funcEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(scope).
> 3. Let envRec be funcEnv's EnvironmentRecord.
> 4. Let name be StringValue of BindingIdentifier.
> 5. Perform envRec.CreateImmutableBinding(name, false).
> 6. Let closure be FunctionCreate(Normal, FormalParameters, FunctionBody, funcEnv).
> 7. Perform MakeConstructor(closure).
> 8. Perform SetFunctionName(closure, name).
> 9. Set closure.[[SourceText]] to the source text matched by FunctionExpression.
> 10. Perform envRec.InitializeBinding(name, closure).
> 11. Return closure.

The important point is the **.5** which does make the name of the function an [immutable binding](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-15).

---

- In the first case, you try to reassign this *Immutable Binding*. **It throws**
- In the second case however, your named function is not a *FunctionExpression*, but a *FunctionDeclaration*, which has [different behavior](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-instantiatefunctionobject).
- In the last case, it's a *FunctionExpression* and to this regards does the same as the first one.