# Why the function's log is the function itself?

Tags: javascript

I have encountered a problem that if the IFEE function's name is the same with variable's name in it. the output is the function itself. Why?

```js
var b = 10;
(function b() {
  b = 20;
  console.log(b);
})();
```

Comment: Because a local variable shadows the outer scope variable when they are sharing the name.

Comment: Great find @user4642212! I was sure there was one...and that I wouldn't be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Named function expressions create a read only variable in their own scope which matches their name and references themselves.

This is useful for writing recursive functions.

Comment: But why the variable is read only?

Comment: @ChenLee Because the spec says so. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882321/4642212).